# How can I call stored procedure within a procedure and print the output in same line?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I call a stored procedure within a procedure and print the output in same line.
For example my full name is 'Alex Bob' and I have created 2 procedure each for firstname(p1) and lastname(p2) like this:

```
-- Procedure 1:

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p1(fn in out varchar) 
IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(fn);
END;

-- Procedure 2: 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p2(ln in out varchar) 
IS
BEGIN
    p1('Alex');
    dbms_output.put_line(ln);
END;

-- Calling procedure
exec p2('Bob');
```

Now this will give me output like this:

```
Alex
Bob
```

But I want to print name together (in a single line) and for this I tried calling procedure within procedure by creating local variable and calling procedure & storing returned value in that variable. Here is my revised code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p1(fn in varchar)
IS
BEGIN
declare 
cn varchar;
cn := exec p2('Bob');
dbms_output.put_line(fn || cn); 
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p2(ln in out varchar)
IS
BEGIN
ln := ln;
END;

exec p1('Alex');
```

but this doesn't work as expected. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Private Procedure` to achieve this. See below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p1 (fn IN  VARCHAR)
AS
   v_nam varchar2(100):='Bob'; 
   --private Procedure
   PROCEDURE p2 (LN IN OUT VARCHAR)
   IS
   BEGIN
      null;
   END;

BEGIN
   p2(lN => v_nam);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (fn ||' '||v_nam);
END;
```

Execution:

```
SQL>  exec p1('Alex');

Alex Bob

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, literals cannot be passed as `in OUT` parameters - only `IN`, simply because you cannot assign anything to a literal, can you? Now back to the problem at hand. If you need those two procedures be able to print on the same line, use `dbms_output.put()` in all procedures but the last one and in the last one call `dbms_output.put_line()`. here is an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p1(fn in varchar2) 
IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put(fn);
END;
/
-- Procedure 2: 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p2(ln in varchar2) 
IS
BEGIN
    p1('Alex ');
    dbms_output.put(ln);
END;
/

create or replace procedure p3(ln in varchar2)
is
begin
  p2('Bob ');
  dbms_output.put_line(ln);
end;



exec p3('is a nice guy')
```

Result:

```
Alex Bob is a nice guy

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

[Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#BABJCAJA)